# Detect if mousedown is for a selection drag

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am tracking the mousedown state and not only does Secondary mouse button click trigger the `mousedown` event while failing to deliver on a `mouseup` event, so does the situation of dragging on something selected (note this is different from dragging *to select*).

I am currently experiencing this on *Safari 6 on a Mac* and I'll report back if I see it on other platforms/systems.

Is there a way to intercept this so that my JS program can be not confused about what's going on? For the secondary button situation I simply check `event.which === 3` in my handler and just don't mark my button as down, and that takes care of that, but I am using the left button to initiate drag on a selected bit of text as well..

Comment: what do you want to make with it? i can help you if you can give a example to me! I had a same question tommorow and i used a technique which worked. Maybe, that technique work for you also!

Comment: You had the same question tomorrow? I find that hard to believe.

Comment: well, you looked my comment now tell me waht you wanted to do with it?

Comment: I'm building a general purpose library and I need to track the state of user input (in this case the mouse button and position states). When dragging on a selection this breaks a bit.

Comment: any example? of it? or a image?

Comment: I've described it. The `mouseup` does not fire when you drag a selection. Which part of that needs to be clarified?

Comment: writing code now, make a fiddle and give you!

Comment: see this: http://jsfiddle.net/yjSjD/1/

Comment: Thanks. I tried it and it is quite easy to make it "stuck". just try click-dragging on "Increase" or "Decrease", even after letting go the `mouseup` never runs so it just keeps going. This is even worse than the issue with selection because I can disable selections but it's much harder (if it is even possible) to make links un-draggable.

Comment: well, this is due to because i have defined mouseup event on anchor element with class i and when you drag the link on the document and leave it then the mouseup event occurs on the document not anchor so, it keeps on moving! :)

Comment: Ah, perhaps. But there are situations (like dragging a selected bit of text) where the mouseup occurs *nowhere*.

Comment: well, thats difficult to make :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The specific issue here is that `mousedown` is not triggered when dragging a selection.

The solution is to simply prevent selection where it may become problematic.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I understand what you want to do, but checking which button has been pressed may involve a bit more work other that checking the which property.

Have a look [this quirksmode page](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_properties.html#button). The **rightclick** section contains some code that may help you.

A very thorough explanation on mouse events is also [available here](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_mouse.html). It can really help you deal with browser quirks.